# Thunderbird wants to purge deleted messages from disk but I want to recover them - where are they?

Tags: linux, email, thunderbird, imap

A few days back I accidentally deleted several messages due to keystrokes being fed to the wrong application.  However, I have hope for recovery because whenever Thunderbird starts I get this message:

> The messages you have deleted can be purged from disk. This operation will save about 22.3 MB of disk space. Select the option below to let Thunderbird do this automatically without asking you.”

The problem is, I cannot figure out where these messages are at or how to undelete them.  The deleted messages were on IMAP but my IMAP trash contains only two e-mails of about 7k in size (from looking in ~/.thunderbird/5xxxxxx1.default-release/ImapMail/.  The local trash folder does not show any messages.  I tried search for "in:trash" but it just returned messages *containing* the word "trash".  Is there somewhere else I should be looking?

Update: I am still dealing with this problem 4 months later, always having to be super careful to not accidentally allow it to compact folders. Now the startup message is saying that it *needs* to perform this maintenance to remain efficient, and I found some posts that claim that you are basically stupid if you don't allow it to do compacting and that it could lead to corruption.

Comment: Does [How to recover deleted / lost Thunderbird messages](https://www.emailadepts.com/blog/restore-deleted-lost-thunderbird-messages.htm) answer your question?

Comment: @DavidPostill No, I actually read that before I asked the question.  However, I do have an additional data point. When I edit the MBOX file that should have had the message before it was deleted, there is nothing with any `X-Mozilla-Status:` other than `0001`. My version of Thunderbird is too new to use the extension mentioned.  The Recover Tool it mentions doesn't work with Linux.

Comment: (1) Do you have a "Recoverable Items" folder locally or on the IMAP server? (2) please comment on [this article](https://www.easeus.com/file-recovery/recover-permanently-deleted-emails-in-outlook.html).

Comment: @harrymc (1) i do not,  (2) this article seems to be for Microsoft Outlook on Windows/Mac, not Thunderbird under Linux so I'm not sure what you want me to say here.

Comment: The article may indeed not apply to your case. (1) I don't know what Outlook looks like on Linux, but: If you click on "Deleted items", do you see in the Folder pane inside the Clean Up group an icon called "Recover Deleted Items"? (2) If you can use Outlook on the Web, you might find this option in there.

Comment: 1) have you checked Tools -> Account Settings -> Synchronisation & Storage -> Advanced ... ? It could be that your thrash folder is not being synchronized. 2) Have you checked on your imap server (through a webmail client, if available), if the items are somehow stuck there and don't appear in Thunderbird (in imap, the "master" for synchronized folders is always the server!)?  3) Are you sure the messages were deleted and not moved to some other folder, e.g. have you done a search over all folders ?

Comment: Also check Tools -> Account Settings -> Server Settings -> Server Settings. There's a voice: "when I delete a message ..." with the choice to move it, mark as deleted or remove it immediately. The possible solution will vary according to your settings there

Comment: @harrymc I found some sqlite databases that I didn't see before, but I haven't had time yet to poke around too much in them.

Comment: @1NN So the thing is, Thunderbird seems to be wanting to compact local files, which suggests to me that the deleted stuff is already locally on disk.  I did find a few folders including trash which weren't marked for offline use and check them, but that didn't seem to cause any deleted messages to show up (e.g. via X-Mozilla-Status). The "when I delete a message" is set to move it to Trash on the IMAP folder, but this file locally is only 33k in size.

Comment: Could it be that your keystrokes did something else rather than delete the emails ? (archive, move, ..) If you have any clue about what the "deleted" emails are about/contain/how old they are, do an advanced search over all folders: `ctrl+shift+f` or go to edit->find->search messages. If they are in your DB, they will appear.

Comment: @1NN i wish i knew!

Comment: @Michael It's getting a little confused. I see it in this way. Specify the settings of Thunderbird when the mail were deleted and now (deleting options, paths...). Find each file is (was) using Thunderbird. Backup all of them. In Kmail (e.g.) the IMAP account may be managed saving each email separated. If so you should find with the correct path on your disk among the deleted files (not so cosy under Linux, if they are still there). Else if they were stored in a mbox (-like) db file you should search manually inside there. No matter how big it is.

Comment: Since Thunderbird prompts you to compact and expunge the deleted letters, you have some possibility to find them still somewhere there. But if your program has moved them to a directory (trash) by deleting them immediately it is not said that you will still be able to find them (they may be locally partially or totally overwritten). Among other things, if you did not make an offline backup of the trash directory at the time, its status may now depend on how the provider worked on it...Note that in some countries ISPs are required by law to keep a copy of each email for 3 years... you may ask.

Comment: @Hastur I agree with you that since it's prompting me to compact they should still be around somewhere.  And this is a work e-mail account - I guess I could ping IT and ask about backups.

Comment: Unfortunately it can be asking to compact the db in which there could only be links to external files where mails and attachments were stored... but the db may also store the whole email body and attachments. It depends on settings. Note not only your IT guys should have a backup, but even (if external) the service provider**s** (who sent and who received). If you identified the db you can access them with programs able to reindex them (always on a backup copy of the files).

Answer (score 0):

Have you located the mbox file and reviewed it manually? Basically, Thunderbird saves mail to an mbox file such as "inbox.mbox". This is essentially a text file with all of your mail, deleted and archived included.

I would do a search for *.mbox and then open it in wordpad. Anything actually in your mail will be there. Even deleted emails will be there but marked as deleted. You may have multiple mbox files but they all do the same thing. There is also a nifty mbox viewer that can be downloaded at: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mbox-viewer/files/latest/download. I haven't used it in years so I can't remember if everything from the actual file shows up or if they're filtered.

If you have purged it then whatever mail would be there is gone as the purpose of purging is to shrink that file. I would then look to any system or email backups made in the past if you do such things. For example, I run a backup of my system drive monthly and save to an external drive. I keep each month for the last 90 days, and out of the three I keep one for longer term for 6 months. I keep data backups longer. If you don't keep regular image backups, this may be a reason for you to begin doing so.

Comment: I did look at the MBOX file (see my second comment above) - there is nothing with deleted status, and manually trying to figure out where 20MB of deleted messages are in a 4GB file when I'm not even sure what the messages are isn't going to work.